# Host aborting connection while sending an email using Gmail API and Python

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I won't bother you with the whole code - this is my first question here so please be patient.

I am trying to send an email with a .zip file attached, using the Gmail API. The whole idea is to automate sending emails with data through Gmail, while retaining the standard level of security.

This is how I authenticate:

```
def authenticate(self):
        CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
        OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
        STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        credentials = STORAGE.get()
        if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
            credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        self.service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

then using the example, that Google gave, almost as it was, I prepare my message:

```
def CreateMessageWithAttachment(self, sender, to, subject, message_text, file_strings):
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['to'] = to
        message['from'] = sender
        message['subject'] = subject

        msg = MIMEText(message_text)
        message.attach(msg)

        for path in file_strings:
            content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(path)

            main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
            fp = open(path, 'rb')
            msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
            msg.set_payload(fp.read())
            fp.close()
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=path.split("\\")[-1])
            message.attach(msg)

        return  {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

and finally I send it using almost exactly their example again:

```
 def SendMessage(self, message, address):
        try:
            message = (self.service.users().messages().send(userId=self.user_id, body=message).execute())
            return "Message to %s successfuly sent at: %s." %(address , datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            return  'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

As a result I get this lovely wall of text for one particular .zip file with size 9.8MB (I was able to send it through gmail manually):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeliveryManager.py", line 264, in <module>
    dispatch.run()
  File "DeliveryManager.py", line 180, in run
    self.sendMessages()
  File "DeliveryManager.py", line 248, in sendMessages
    log = self.sender.SendMessage(message, address)
  File "DeliveryManager.py", line 79, in SendMessage
    message = (self.service.users().messages().send(userId=self.user_id, body=message).execute())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 716, in execute
    body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 547, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1593, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1335, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1291, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "c:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "c:\python27\lib\ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>Exit code: 1
```

I guess I am forming the message improperly, but I can't figure why and where...

Comment: Are you able to send the message without issue if you *don't* include an attachment?

Comment: Yes and also some of the messages are passing through with the attachment if it does not contain that particular combination of files.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a particular file or combination of files?  Have you tried `print content_type` to see if its a misdetection issue or the issue is related to the detected content type?

Comment: Yes, the guessed type seems right, attempting to send two messages and getting:

content_type application/x-zip-compressed
content_type application/x-zip-compressed

Comment: And I tried sending the files unzipped one by one - not a problem there, also tried sending some other zips without a problem and a .7z file also without a problem.

Comment: I guess this explains the problem to some extent: Note: The Gmail API should not be used to replace IMAP for full-fledged email client access. Instead, see IMAP and SMTP. * taken from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem !

I had this:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode='w')
```

Then I installed zlib and changed the compression to:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

There are no more errors of the type ... or any type for now.
I guess Gmail just doesn't like the default compression of the zipfile module, in some cases.